# Run javascript es6 code in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, ecmascript-6, grunt-babel

I am exploring JavaScript es6 code in angularjs app and used grunt babel to compile the es6 to es5.

My unit test (jasmine) doesn't run with es6 code using phantomjs.

Whats best way to run test? Is there any plugin to use for jasmine to run es6 code?

Comment: See karma-webpack and build your test with webpack. This work for me.

Comment: Thanks.That seems good,is it possible to do without using karma? Currently i am working on transpile(es6 to es5) code for unit testing.

Answer (score 6):

You can configure Jasmine to use Babel as a helper and transform your code on the fly.

Install `babel-register` module:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-register
```

And register it as a Jasmine helper

In your `spec/support/jasmine.json` file make the following changes:

```
{
  "helpers": [
    "../node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js"
  ]
}
```

For more information see the [piecioshka/test-jasmine-babel](https://github.com/piecioshka/test-jasmine-babel) repository on Github.

Babel 6.x does not ship with any transformations enabled by default. You need to explicitly tell it what transformations to run. You are already using Babel so those modules should be installed. If not, you can install the ES2015 Preset using npm:

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

Assuming you have installed Babel and the ES2015 Preset, in order to enable it you have to define it in your `.babelrc` file, like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Comment: what is the solution for babel 7? This doesn't work

Comment: For me karma was the only working solution.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a minimal setup example for **Babel 7+, Jasmine 3.5.0**, project structure:

```
☁  jasmine-examples [master] ⚡  tree -a -L 3 -I "node_modules|coverage|.git|.nyc_output"
.
├── .babelrc
├── .editorconfig
├── .gitignore
├── .nycrc
├── .prettierrc
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── jasmine.json
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── src
    ├── helpers
    │   ├── console-reporter.js
    │   └── jsdom.js
    └── stackoverflow
        ├── 60138152
        ├── 61121812
        ├── 61277026
        ├── 61643544
        └── 61985831

8 directories, 12 files
```

devDependencies:

```
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
"@babel/register": "^7.9.0",
"jasmine": "^3.5.0",
```

npm scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "jasmine --config=./jasmine.json",
  "coverage": "nyc npm run test && nyc report --reporter=html"
}
```

`jasmine.json`:

```
{
  "spec_dir": "src",
  "spec_files": ["**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)"],
  "helpers": ["helpers/**/*.js", "../node_modules/@babel/register/lib/node.js"],
  "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
  "random": true
}
```

`.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Here we need to watch out that the file paths of `helpers`:

> Array of filepaths (and globs) relative to spec_dir to include before jasmine specs

The file paths in the `helpers` option are **relative to spec_dir**, **NOT** relative project root path. Which means you should use

```
"../node_modules/@babel/register/lib/node.js"
```

**NOT**

```
"./node_modules/@babel/register/lib/node.js"
```

`src/61985831/myClass.js`:

```js
export class MyClass {
  constructor() {}
}
```

`src/61985831/myClass.spec.js`:

```js
import { MyClass } from './myClass';

describe('my class', function () {
  var myClassInstance;
  beforeEach(function () {
    myClassInstance = new MyClass();
  });

  it('is an instance of MyClass', function () {
    expect(myClassInstance).toBeInstanceOf(MyClass);
  });
});
```

The outcome for the test:

```
> jasmine-examples@1.0.0 test /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jasmine-examples
> jasmine --config=./jasmine.json "/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jasmine-examples/src/stackoverflow/61985831/myClass.spec.js"


Executing 1 defined specs...
Running in random order... (seed: 66758)

Test Suites & Specs:
(node:57105) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental

1. my class
   ✔ is an instance of MyClass (4ms)

>> Done!


Summary:

  Passed
Suites:  1 of 1
Specs:   1 of 1
Expects: 1 (0 failures)
Finished in 0.017 seconds
```

repo here: https://github.com/mrdulin/jasmine-examples

Comment: Very nice work, many jasmine examples. However, for me it did not work.
I updated every module in package.json, removed the jasmine-pretty-html-reporter (because it is depended on a very old jasmine version). After npm run test I got:
import { MyClass } from './myClass';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
Which is where I stuck in my project setup.

Answer (score 2):

I spent quite some time to make babel & jasmine to cooperate, so i should post my solution here:

install `babel-cli` package, do standard babel config (for me it was `.babelrc` file)

i created custom runner file: `bin/jasmine`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
./node_modules/.bin/babel-node ./node_modules/.bin/jasmine $@ --config=spec/support/jasmine.json
```

that way even passing arguments works! `bin/jasmine -h` while path to config conveniently always defined

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it working for babel 7+ by executing the following command in package.json:

```
"test": "jasmine --config=jasmine.json --require=@babel/register"
```