# failing to import with jasmine and babel

Tags: javascript, jasmine, babeljs

I am trying to install jasmine to my project, but I keep getting the error

```
> jasmine

/home/munhunger/develop/dnd/dmScreen/src/lib/quadTree.spec.js:1
import quadTree from './quadTree';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Loader.requireShim [as require_] (/home/munhunger/develop/dnd/dmScreen/node_modules/jasmine/lib/loader.js:35:3)
    at /home/munhunger/develop/dnd/dmScreen/node_modules/jasmine/lib/loader.js:28:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

This seems to be a fairly common issue, and I've seen a few questions about it here on SO.
For example here [Run javascript es6 code in Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32879986/run-javascript-es6-code-in-jasmine/62015012#62015012)

It seems straightforwards and I've done as described there (to the best of my knowledge). But I still get the same error.

So I have babel installed, with this config

```
//.babelrc
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

and I have configured a helper in my jasmine conf

```
//spec/support/jasmine.json
{
    "spec_dir": "src",
    "spec_files": ["**/*.[sS]pec.js"],
    "helpers": ["helpers/**/*.js", "../node_modules/@babel/register/lib/node.js"],
    "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
    "random": false
}
```

I am running it without any special config

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jasmine"
}
```

But I still can't run my tests.
So am I missing something obvious, or why isn't this working?

Here is the git repo(and commit) where it is failing
https://github.com/munHunger/dnd/tree/e2ab4c7d3cd78b01449e41679bdf6ad363ce711c/dmScreen

Comment: Is that the *full* error message?

Comment: updated, now it is the full error message

Comment: same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when attempting to set up jasmine with typescript.

I eventually traced it to the "spec_dir" config entry causing the issue!

If you remove that line and add the value as a prefix to your "spec_files" entries, it may work. That did the trick for me.

```
// jasmine.json
{
  "spec_files": ["src/**/*.[sP]pec.js"],
...
}
```

Feels like a bug.